# z-index not working with overflow to overlap and scrollbar

Tags: html, css, styles, overflow, z-index

I got the following issue:

I'm trying to display a few `<div.content>` with content in it. Limited in size to a `<div.holder>` as parent with `overflow` set, so that you can scroll down to see all `<div.content>`. The `<div.content>` are overlapping the `<div.holder>` for styling purpose. And everything is wrapped in a `<div.container>`.

But the `<div.content>` won't display over the `<div.holder>` element with `z-index` or anything. It's rendered inside the `<div.holder>` element, without scrollbar it's rendered outside, like i want.

How can i get the Scrollbar and that the `<div.content>` will overlap its parent `<div.holder>`?

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QTMPf/5/) for the issue. Thank you.

EDIT:

Trying to accomplish this:
[image: Photoshoped result example for the fiddle]

For this styling purpose:
[image: Use case]

Is this even possible? I'm not bound to just use HTML&CSS, just need that thing start working.

Comment: So you want the scroll bar and the content to overflow it's container? Not sure you can get that functionality. (If I read it correctly)

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall Like shown in the fiddle, i want to use the scrollbar on the container and the content to overlap the container

Comment: You can't do that with css as what you're trying to do is at odds. What's your use case? or Why are you trying to get this functionality?

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I Uploaded 2 Pictures to describe my case. I want that div.content to look like they're comming from back to front.

Comment: You can fake the background on the left side if the divs are a set height to get the same look/feel.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall from which div can i fake that background? the hole thing have to scroll

Comment: Like this http://i.imgur.com/gCujf.jpg

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I'm realy sry if i wasn't specific enough. The .holder is scrollable with the .content in it, and that area where you pointed in your img, is the .container, which isn't scrollable. But is there no solution with HTML or CSS to do this trick?

Comment: Yes, Fake the background of .holder, just extend the width like 20px for your "ribbon". Exactly like the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Z-index will only work on elements with position. So its not doing anything to .foo
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I forgot it on the Fiddle, but it's neither working with `position:relative`